# Manipulate incoming stream of data in realtime

Tags: java

I read a file of numbers, and I want to click a button. When the button is clicked the numbers will output the average instead of just the numbers without interrupting the incoming stream of data.

aka I want to manipulate the stream in realtime. That is what im wondering.

How can this be done?

Ty

Comment: You want to manipulate the numbers being read *while* they're being read?  It is possible, but you need to use a thread to perform the read and be able to pass cues to it when button is pressed.  It would also have to be a rather large file to have any time to click while it is being read unless you plan on artificially inserting delays.

Comment: Yes that I what I want, and I have delay to be able to simulate events. So I have to use threading? One that outputs the file and another one that process the output somehow in realtime?

Comment: Please refer to my answer.  The short answer is yes, you have to use threading, otherwise you can't trigger a change from a button.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof-of-concept application.  It uses a `SwingWorker` to count from 0 to 99 with a small delay added each time.  The button starts the count and during the count, allows you to cause outputted numbers to be doubled.  Notice that the class member doubleMe is marked `volatile` because it is being read across threads.

Note that I used Java 8 for compactness.

```java
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public class WorkerTest extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {
        public volatile boolean doubleMe = false;

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                publish(doubleMe ? i*2 : i);

                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> numberList) {
            super.process(arg0);

            numberList.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    private WorkerTest worker = null;
    private final JButton btn;

    public MainFrame() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        btn = new JButton("Go!");

        btn.addActionListener(ae -> {
            if(worker == null || worker.isDone()) {
                btn.setText("Toggle double!");

                worker = new WorkerTest();
                worker.addPropertyChangeListener(l -> {
                    if("state".equals(l.getPropertyName()) && StateValue.DONE.equals(l.getNewValue())) {
                        btn.setText("Go!");
                    }
                });
                worker.execute();
            } else {
                worker.doubleMe = !worker.doubleMe;
            }
        });
        add(btn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
            mf.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

In your case, you'd be reading numbers, not generating them, but the concept is the same.  The doubleMe acts as a way to communicate to the thread to change its behavior while it is still working.  Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: wow thanks. it does what i was thinking. now i have to test it on my own. i will come back later.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is a naive method to take the average with the live stream of numbers.

You can do something like this:

private int sum =0;
private int n = 0; // no. of nums read

```
func(){
 while / for:
 nextNum = // code to read number in a loop
 sum += nextNum;
 n++;
}
```

And then you can use event handler for catching button click event
and on button click, you can return avg =  sum / n.

However as Neil pointed out, if you want uninterrupted stream and also to avoid race condition, you should use threads.

EDIT: By race condition I mean  that suppose you click when sum value was updated but n was not updated. In that case you will get the wrong result for average.

Comment: yes the problem is not to get the average, but do it as you said uninterrupted.